# I can't compile plugins for Qt 5.15.2 Debian

Tags: debian, qt5, qt-designer

I'm on Debian 11 and installed QtCreator IDE based on Qt 5.15.2 and with Qt Designer also based on Qt 5.15.2.
I want to create a custom widget to use as a plugin on Qt Designer. To start I used the Qt Creator IDE wizard to create the new plugin. Without writing anything more than what the wizard created, I went on to compile it within the Qt Creator IDE, but it immediately gave me an error on the line:

```
QT   += uiplugin
```

How is it possible ? Why does this happen with code that is provided by Qt itself ?

Comment: What is the error?